# How to make json.dumps in Python ignore a non-serializable field

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, construct

I am trying to serialize the output of parsing some binary data with the Construct2.9 library. I want to serialize the result to JSON.

`packet` is an instance of a Construct class `Container`.

Apparently it contains a hidden `_io` of type `BytesIO` - see output of `dict(packet)` below:

```
{
'packet_length': 76, 'uart_sent_time': 1, 'frame_number': 42958, 
'subframe_number': 0, 'checksum': 33157, '_io': <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f81c3153728>, 
'platform':661058, 'sync': 506660481457717506, 'frame_margin': 20642,
'num_tlvs': 1, 'track_process_time': 593, 'chirp_margin': 78,
'timestamp': 2586231182, 'version': 16908293
}
```

Now, calling `json.dumps(packet)` obviously leads to a TypeError:

```
...

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 237, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 198, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 256, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f81c3153728> is not JSON serializable
```

However what I am confused about, is that running `json.dumps(packet, skipkeys=True)` results in the exact same error, while I would expect it to skip the `_io` field. What is the problem here? Why is `skipkeys` not allowing me to skip the `_io` field?

I got the code to work by overriding `JSONEncoder` and returning `None` for fields of `BytesIO` type, but that means my serialized string contains loads of `"_io": null` elements, which I would prefer not to have at all...

Comment: `skipkeys` only ignores non-primitive keys, not values

Comment: @EdwardMinnix ah, I knew I was missing something...
is there any way then to skip the encoding of a certain field altogether?

Comment: @mz8i did you find out why the changes in Construct2.9 produces `_io`? I've been using Construct for years and converting to json nicely now until the 2.9 update.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Keys with a leading `_` underscore are not really 'hidden', they are just more strings to JSON. The Construct `Container` class is just a dictionary with ordering, the `_io` key is not anything special to that class.

You have two options:

- implement a `default` hook that just returns a replacement value.
- Filter out the key-value pairs that you know can't work *before* serialising.

and perhaps a third, but a casual scan of the Construct project pages doesn't tell me if it is available: have Construct output JSON or at least a JSON-compatible dictionary, perhaps by using adapters.

The default hook can't prevent the `_io` key from being added to the output, but would let you at least avoid the error:

```
json.dumps(packet, default=lambda o: '<not serializable>')
```

Filtering can be done recursively; the [`@functools.singledispatch()` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) can help keep such code clean:

```
from functools import singledispatch

_cant_serialize = object()

@singledispatch
def json_serializable(object, skip_underscore=False):
    """Filter a Python object to only include serializable object types

    In dictionaries, keys are converted to strings; if skip_underscore is true
    then keys starting with an underscore ("_") are skipped.

    """
    # default handler, called for anything without a specific
    # type registration.
    return _cant_serialize

@json_serializable.register(dict)
def _handle_dict(d, skip_underscore=False):
    converted = ((str(k), json_serializable(v, skip_underscore))
                 for k, v in d.items())
    if skip_underscore:
        converted = ((k, v) for k, v in converted if k[:1] != '_')
    return {k: v for k, v in converted if v is not _cant_serialize}

@json_serializable.register(list)
@json_serializable.register(tuple)
def _handle_sequence(seq, skip_underscore=False):
    converted = (json_serializable(v, skip_underscore) for v in seq)
    return [v for v in converted if v is not _cant_serialize]

@json_serializable.register(int)
@json_serializable.register(float)
@json_serializable.register(str)
@json_serializable.register(bool)  # redudant, supported as int subclass
@json_serializable.register(type(None))
def _handle_default_scalar_types(value, skip_underscore=False):
    return value
```

I have the above implementation an additional `skip_underscore` argument too, to explicitly skip keys that have a `_` character at the start. This would help skip all additional 'hidden' attributes the Construct library is using.

Since `Container` is a `dict` subclass, the above code will automatically handle instances such as `packet`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters this doesn't appear to work for nested objects - is there a nifty generic way to achieve this and have it work for any object? e.g. I have an Author object that has a Publications property which is an array of publication objects... anybody?

Comment: @MarkZhukovsky: this **does** support nested objects, because each registered function recurses. So a dictionary inside a list is handled because the function handling lists calls `json_serializable()` on each element of the list. You just have to register additional functions for other types, such as your Author type. Make sure to call `json_serializable()` for each attribute of the type. The object in the question is a subclass of `dict`, which is why we don't have to register anything special for it, but apparently your `Author` type is not.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you for the quick response.  I can indeed get it to work by adding Author and Publication, and I was off-base about the nested comment. All I did though was copy the function for _handle_dict and changes d.items() to d.__dict__.items() and it worked. Is there a way to generically handle any class-types to do this so no manual adding of the specific classes would be required? I am coming from a diff language so thanks for your patience.

Comment: @MarkZhukovsky: you could derive your classes from a base class (doesn't even need any methods or attributes), then register that. And I'd use `return json_serializable(vars(instance))` as the registered function body.

Answer (score 26):

Ignoring a non-serializable field requires heavy extra logic as correctly pointed out in all previous answers.

If you don't really need to exclude the field, then you can generate a default value instead:

```py
def safe_serialize(obj):
  default = lambda o: f"<<non-serializable: {type(o).__qualname__}>>"
  return json.dumps(obj, default=default)

obj = {"a": 1, "b": bytes()} # bytes is non-serializable by default
print(safe_serialize(obj))
```

That will produce this result:

```
{"a": 1, "b": "<<non-serializable: bytes>>"}
```

This code will print the type name, which might be useful if you want to implement your custom serializers later on.

Answer (score 4):

[`skipkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) doesn't do what you might think it does - it instructs the [`json.JSONEncoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) to skip keys that are not of a *basic* type, not the values of the keys - i.e. if your had a `dict` `{object(): "foobar"}` it would skip the `object()` key, whereas without `skipkeys` set to `True` it would raise a `TypeError`.

You can overload [`JSONEncoder.iterencode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder.iterencode) (and its underbelly) and perform look-ahead filtering there, but you'll end up pretty much rewriting the `json` module, slowing it down in the process as you won't be able to benefit from the compiled parts. What I'd suggest you is to pre-process your data via iterative filtering and skip keys/types you don't want in your final JSON. Then the `json` module should be able to process it without any additional instructions. Something like:

```
import collections

class SkipFilter(object):

    def __init__(self, types=None, keys=None, allow_empty=False):
        self.types = tuple(types or [])
        self.keys = set(keys or [])
        self.allow_empty = allow_empty  # if True include empty filtered structures

    def filter(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, collections.Mapping):
            result = {}  # dict-like, use dict as a base
            for k, v in data.items():
                if k in self.keys or isinstance(v, self.types):  # skip key/type
                    continue
                try:
                    result[k] = self.filter(v)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
            if result or self.allow_empty:
                return result
        elif isinstance(data, collections.Sequence):
            result = []  # a sequence, use list as a base
            for v in data:
                if isinstance(v, self.types):  # skip type
                    continue
                try:
                    result.append(self.filter(v))
                except ValueError:
                    pass
            if result or self.allow_empty:
                return result
        else:  # we don't know how to traverse this structure...
            return data  # return it as-is, hope for the best...
        raise ValueError
```

Then create your filter:

```
import io

preprocessor = SkipFilter([io.BytesIO], ["_io"])  # double-whammy skip of io.BytesIO
```

In this case skipping just by type should suffice, but in case the `_io` key holds some other undesirable data this guarantees it won't be in the final result. Anyway, you can then just filter the data prior to passing it to the `JSONEncoder`:

```
import json

json_data = json.dumps(preprocessor.filter(packet))  # no _io keys or io.BytesIO data...
```

Of course, if your structure contains some other exotic data or data that is represented in JSON differently based on its type, this approach might mess it up as it turns all mappings into `dict` and all sequences into `list`. However, for general usage this should be more than enough.