# Python Object of type WebElement is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, selenium

I want convert dict to json using json.dumps but i have problem with WebElement.

I got `TypeError: Object of type WebElement is not JSON serializable`

This my example code :

```
def x():
  p = {'a':'a','b':driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)}
  return p
dict = x()
print(json.dumps(dict))
```

I want convert json except WebElement but without modify x function.

Comment: json only knows about standard variable types -- integers, strings, lists, and so on.  It can't handle custom classes such as `WebElement`.  You can convert the element into a string with `'b': str(element)`.

Comment: @JohnGordon but i cant modify to str(element), its a dict from return function

Comment: What do you mean you can't modify it?  You can call `str()` on anything.

Comment: @JohnGordon i updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved using `json.dumps(dict, default=lambda o: '<not serializable>')` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/51674892/12716228

Answer (score 0):

Your element object is not serializable. if you can convert the element object to a string. After you can set to b key.

```
element = str(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath))
dict = {'a':'a','b':element}
print(json.dumps(dict))
```

Comment: p = {'a':'a','b':str(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath))}

Comment: without modify x function